# Importing Android Studio Project to Xamarin Project

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I created a Firebase Cloud Messaging Android Application for an internship for integration with the firm's existing app. Little did I know that I will have to integrate the features into a Xamarin Project.

Currently, there is no direct Xamarin Support/Implementation Available for an FCM based notification system but I have spent a week over Firebase and I am in no mood to let it in vain. If someone could help me out on how to go about this, please do. Open to all kind of workaround/suggestions.

Comment: Here is [the community's opinion on "urgent" questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495).

Comment: Thankyou. (un)luckily I am under a deadline here.

Comment: Respectfully, your deadlines are your own, and it is entirely unacceptable for you to attempt to transfer that pressure onto volunteers. They have their own deadlines, I should think!

Answer (score 1):

if you can make it pop pout as a library (.jar) not application (.apk) you could try to import it as Bindings Library project

Comment: Thanks...But I have not yet used Xamarin so you'll have to be slightly more descriptive..I guess.

Comment: The Bindings Library project takes the jar library and makes it usable as c# library (but it will be a project in solution) by binding the functions in the jar.